# PreparedStatement - getting the last ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

It is possible to execute the following `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("select 'a' as a; select 'b' as b");
s.execute();
```

That is, the statement can contain more than one SQL statement.

However, if I call `s.getResultSet()`, it only takes the first query into consideration (the one returning "a"). How can I get the *last* `ResultSet` from this statement?

Comment: Why don't you split the statements?

Comment: provide some examples, why you need to use more than one statement?

Comment: What database? Some databases and/or JDBC drivers do not support multiple queries in one call or multiple resultsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `getMoreResults()`which moves to this *Statement* object's next result,and implicitly closes any current ResultSet object(s) obtained with the method `getResultSet` and then again calling `getResultSet()`.